# how make a alias mixing with clearcase command and shell command

Tags: shell

I make a alias like :

```
alias a 'ct setview myview ;  cd /vobs/project/foo'
```

but this alias just partly works : it can set view , but it does not take me to 
/vobs/project/foo . so could you tell me why does this happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forgot a '='? `alias a='ct setview myview ;  cd /vobs/project/foo'`

Answer (score 1):

What about 'ct setview -exec' ?